# I can't know why the answer is o(nlogn)

Tags: python, time-complexity

```
def foo(x):
  n = len(x)
  if n <= 1:
    return 17
  return foo(x[:n//2]) + foo(x[n//2:])
```

why the running time is `O(nlogn)`?

I was expecting `O(logn)`

Comment: the n=len(x) and x is a list

Answer (score 0):

Each slice creates a new list. You can imagine the original and the slices as in the following diagram, where each row represents a deeper recursion level:

```
   [1,   2,   3,   4,   5,   6,   7,   8]             │
   [1,   2,   3,   4], [5,   6,   7,   8]        recursion depth
   [1,   2], [3,   4], [5,   6], [7,   8]             │
   [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8]             ▼
```

So you can see that the work for generating the two lists in the second row (of the above diagram) already has a O() complexity. We need to multiply this to cover for the rows that follow. The number of rows (excluding the first -- which is the input) is O(log), so we have O(log).

#### Without slicing

If you would not actually *slice* the list, but would merely tell what the start and end index are of the sublist to consider, then you would omit that slicing work. The code could then look like this:

```
def foo(x, start=0, end=-1):
  if (end == -1) end = len(x)  # default value for `end`
  n = end - start
  if n <= 1:
    return 17
  mid = (start + end) // 2
  return foo(x, start, mid) + foo(x, mid, end)
```

Now the complexity is determined by the number of recursive calls as all actions in the non-recursive code can be taken as having constant time (using [arithmetic complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity#Others)). The number of recursive call doubles in each row in the diagram representation, meaning that the next level always have one more recursive call than all recursive calls at the previous levels together. Therefor there are not more than 2 recursive calls, i.e. it is O().